# Automatically redirect to public view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-1.0

My ASP.NET Core app requires users to login. I created a public action method that allows anonymous users i.e.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Public()
{
   return View();
}
```

Because in my Startup.cs I require authentication, users are automatically redirected to the login page.

[image]

I want to change the behavior and redirect users to the public page automatically and let them click a link to login.

How do I redirect my users to the public page instead of the login page?

Comment: Why not change the `LoginPath` to `/home/public/`? The framework will send unauthenticated users (on actions with `Authorize` attribute) to this path automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change default mapping in App_Start:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters*
        new { controller = "Public", action = "Public", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

## UPDATE

After your comment I think this will answer your needs:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Public");
});
```

Add it to the `ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs

Comment: Will that not send all requests to public? I want to send to Public only those requests that are NOT authenticated. Once a user is logged in, I do want to send them to Home.